# Restore RAID1 configuration with 2 different HardDrives in CentOS-7

Tags: linux, hard-drive, centos, raid-1

We have a server **(HP ProLiant ML10 Gen 9)** that came with Two Identical Hard disks. It was assumed that the server supports hardware RAID 1 (Mirror), and the **CentOS-7** was installed in it. But later we got to know that the server doesn't support Hardware RAID1 and also the software RAID1 was not configured properly.

[***lsblk*** output shows like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lnn0k.png)

```
[root@himalaya ~]# lsblk
NAME                   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                      8:0    0  1.8T  0 disk
└─md126                  9:126  0  1.8T  0 raid1
  ├─md126p1            259:0    0  200M  0 md
  ├─md126p2            259:1    0    1G  0 md
  └─md126p3            259:2    0  1.8T  0 md
    ├─cl_himalaya-root 253:0    0   50G  0 lvm   /
    ├─cl_himalaya-swap 253:1    0  7.8G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    └─cl_himalaya-home 253:2    0  1.8T  0 lvm   /home
sdb                      8:16   0  1.8T  0 disk
├─sdb1                   8:17   0  200M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sdb2                   8:18   0    1G  0 part  /boot
└─sdb3                   8:19   0  1.8T  0 part
sr0                     11:0    1  4.1G  0 rom
```

[***cat /proc/mdstat*** output shows like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFHNH.png)

```
[root@himalaya ~]# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1]
md126 : active raid1 sda[0]
      1953511424 blocks super external:/md127/0 [2/1] [U_]

md127 : inactive sda[0](S)
      3160 blocks super external:imsm

unused devices: <none>
```

As you can see in the above pictures the boot partition is in drive **sdb** whereas the root (/) partition and other files are in the drive **sda**.
Unfortunately the harddisk partitions are not identical.  Now I want to create a **software RAID1** without deleting my content from drive **sda**. So I kindly request someone to help me on how to move the boot partition from the drive **sdb** to drive **sda**. *(the drive **sdb** can be formatted after moving the boot partitions to sda).* and then how to create identical partitions and configure **RAID1** Array.

Please Note: That Drive **sdb** seems to be failed/failing. And the /boot partition is located in this drive **sdb**. But before replacing the harddisk I want to find a way to fix this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hopefully truly needless to ask, but: 1. Any data already on it? 2. Do you have TESTED backups. 3a). If it just is a clean install so far just reinstall, either with HW raid or SW RAID (The Linux SW RAID is pretty good and more flexible than some HW RAID).  3b). If you need to keep the setup. First refer to the back up part, then read up on MD, then test backups again and add to the post what your goal is.

Comment: Hi,
In response to your comments:
1. Yes, we have all the data stored in the drive **sda** (also an Application server is running in this machine). 
2. We do have the backup of the data.
3. Before reinstalling the whole server, It would be great to find a way to fix this issue by moving the boot partition from drive **sdb** to **sda**. since the drive **sbd** is failing/failed. and the drive **sdb** can be replaced if its failed. 
It would be a great help to fix this issue and successfully configure RAID1.

Answer (score 0):

The **/boot/efi** partition cannot exist on the raid partition. therefore, it is more correct to use an sdb disk.
Create a raid1 from sdb3 in a degraded state, e.g:

```
mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 missing /dev/sdb3
```

Create appropriate LVM partitions on it, add them to the Volume Group - and move the data around(**pvmove**).
Then you can format sda - and create a similar partition structure - add to the array on sdb

PS. The system should have one partition with /boot/efi - so some work will have to be done to be able to boot from any of the disks. Google: dosfstools + EFI + RAID

Comment: Hi Zersh,
Thanks for taking your time and replying. I would like to inform you that the drive **sdb** is failed/failing, because of which I cannot move the data from **sda** to **sdb**. I have edited my post as well. 
Kindly let me know for any other possible ways to fix this. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Then plug the New disk into the server without shutting it down (hot-add). You will have 3 disks in the server and you can move the boot partition to it first, then create an array and move the data.